# jQuery BBQ, deep-linking HREF's with a set Class --- Possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, deep-linking

Currently, my understanding of jQuery BBQ is it requires me to use an href like href="#/stufff/123/13"

Problem with that is it requires me to add a # to all my URLs throughout the site which then means non-javascript browsers can't use the site...

My question, is there a way I can simply add a class to all HREFs I want deep linked? something like class="deep-link-it-please".... Ideas? It also creates a headache in Rails which uses link_to which does not support adding a hash # before the URL.. thanks

Comment: It looks to me like the BBQ script does all that for you. All you need to do is run the script and leave your `href` links as you normally would.

Comment: I wish, that doesn't work. still need to add a # in front of links. Is there a class way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a hash to the links you want to hijax?

```
    $('.bbq-nav a').each(function(){
       var nice = $(this).attr('href');
       $(this).attr('href','#' + nice);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to add the hash to your urls if you plan on hijacking them anyway. With normal links inside of my div#container and everything seems to be working fine using this implementation:

```
$("#container a").live('click', function(){
    var hrefRequested = $(this).attr( "href" );

    // Push this URL "state" onto the history hash.
    $.bbq.pushState({ url: hrefRequested });

    // Prevent the default click behavior.
    return false;
});

// Bind a callback that executes when document.location.hash changes.
$(window).bind( "hashchange", function(e) {
    var url = $.bbq.getState( "url" );

    // Used to make sure that when you back up to the page you came in on
    // you don't get an empty page.
    if ( url == undefined ) { url = window.location.href; }

    $('#content-container').load(url + ' #container', function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
            console.log('hooray!');

            // document.title = ;
            // document.location.href = hrefRequested;

            // return false;
        }

        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });

// You probably want to actually do something useful here..
});

// Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need
// to trigger the event now, to handle the hash the page may have
// loaded with.
$(window).trigger("hashchange");
```